# How can I have Angular-Translate preload my translation before I can use it inside my controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying out Angular Translate and I need to use the translations inside my controller, but the controller runs the code before my translation is even loaded yet..here is my code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

angular.module('myApp').config(function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'locales/validation-',
    suffix: '.json'
  });
  // load 'en' table on startup
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$translate', function ($scope, $translate) {

  console.debug($translate('INVALID_INTEGER'));

  $scope.switchLanguage = function (key) {
    $translate.uses(key);
    console.debug($translate('INVALID_INTEGER'));
  };
}]);
```

when calling the `console.debug($translate('INVALID_INTEGER'));` it always shows `INVALID_INTEGER` instead of the real translation, so I conclude that my translation is not yet loaded. I'm new to both Angular and the Angular-Translate, so I'm not sure of what to do next? Do I have to a `promise`, I would prefer a built-in function within `angular-translate` instead. I want simple locale languages which are coming from external and separate `json` files for each language.

EDIT
The real problem I have is that all my translations are used directly inside the controller and not in the view. It seems that `angular-translate` works good for whatever is displayed in the view but in the controller it doesn't refresh the code inside the controller itself. 

Please note that I now have a working Beta Project on Github which is where I use the translation... 
[Angular-Validation](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-validation) *(form validation made easy)*.
 My project is an Angular directive and uses the locales languages, if you run the project and choose a language before loading the template then it works, but after that calling the `$scope.switchLanguage()` won't have any effect on the controller, though any translation on the view would work.

Comment: Weird. I'm using angular-translate 1.1.1 in that exact fashion in  my current project but can't reproduce this. Works as expected. Can you confirm that locales/validation-en.json exists and is valid JSON and contains a translation for INVALID_INTEGER and is being fetched by the browser?

Comment: It seems that this behavior problem is only on the controller side, I don't see that effect on the actual view. But since I really need to handle all messages (languages) on the controller side, then I am not sure on what to do next

Comment: I finished working on a Github project, I use the translation in there, if you have time to take a look at it and maybe help. I would be glad...oh and if you need form validation with angular, mine rocks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so from the github project above it is now apparent that the translation does not work for the following reasons:

1. Link code from ngxValidation directive is run only once on page load and it translates the strings to whatever the current language is set to. The code never runs again unless you fully refresh the page so even if you change the language with $translate.uses() the directive has the strings already translated and cached and does not even try to translate them again.
2. When you click the Load Testing Form multiple times nothing happens - the view is not reloaded (and the directive is not recreated, doh!). And that is not really surprising since it's the same view! Why would angular reload something that is already loaded - it cannot know you changed the translation and you actually *do* want to reload in this particular, special case.

So you would have a couple solutions the simplest of which I think is not to cache the translated strings, translate only just in time - inside validator(). That should always work. If you want to be smart with caching and what not you have to find a way to ensure the cache is always valid :) And as we all know there are only two hard problems in computer science one is cache invalidation and the other one is [insert_whatever_youre_working_on_right_now_here].

---

In detail:

In the directive you're doing:

```
messages[i] = $translate('INVALID_URL');
```

Replace all assignments like this with just:

```
messages[i] = 'INVALID_URL';
```

And then inside the validator function do:

```
if(!isValid) {
  isFieldValid = false;
  message += $translate(messages[j]);
}
```

Comment: I understand and agree with your saying though I'm not sure which piece of code I need to use with angular-translate. Does the `$translate()` function use caching? Actually I think the caching comes from this `$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader()` but that is the only function I found to load different locales with external JSON files. I do want just in time translation, that would be best in my case...but what piece of code would I need to change? BTW I'm still new to Angular... thx

Comment: No. I'm not sure if angular-translate does any caching but that is irrelevant. What is important is that inside the ngxValidation directive you create a table of translated strings that do not get updated when you change the language. Ex. messages[i] = $translate('INVALID_ALPHA');. messages[i] is now the translated string. Once you change the language you would have to recreate it by running messages[i] = $translate('INVALID_ALPHA'); again. But it is not immediately clear how to do that. Thus I suggested using $translate only in the validator and skipping message table altogether.

Comment: Do you mean doing the `$translate()` inside the controller instead of the directive and build the translation table inside the controller on a separate message array that would be passed to the directive is that it?

Comment: Don't touch the controller. Move all $translate() calls in the directive into the validator function. Why? The validator function is run when the input changes so your translated strings will always be up to date. Another way to think about this is always translate at runtime, never do var some = $translate().

Comment: Ok thanks for the code, I will do the change as soon as I get home tonight... BTW, though out of this subject, do you like the concept of my validation project? I'd like to get feedback on that too :)

Comment: That work, though it took me a little while to figure how to pass my error params in another way, so now I'm passing them as an object inside the array, so it works and only load once as you said. `messages[i] = { message: 'INVALID_MIN_CHAR', params: [params[1]] };` ... as I said before let me know if you use my directive and give me feedback, I would appreciate... Thx a lot for help me the translations :)